# Javascript Tree view Search

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement tree view search using JavaScript. I found [search filter in treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61302491/react-js-search-filter-in-treeview) useful, but the answer provided there wasn't the expected output in my scenario.

Example input:

```js
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "templateName": "Item 1",
        "isFolder": "true",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "templateName": "Subitem 1",
                "isFolder": "true",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "templateName": "Misc 1",
                        "isFolder": "true",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": 4,
                                "templateName": "Misc 2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "templateName": "Subitem 2",
                "isFolder": "true",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "templateName": "Misc 3"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "templateName": "Item 2",
        "isFolder": "true",
        "children": [
            {   
                "id": 8,
                "templateName": "Subitem 1",
                "isFolder": "true",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 9,
                        "templateName": "Misc 1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "templateName": "Subitem 8",
                "isFolder": "true",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 11,
                        "templateName": "Misc 4"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 12,
                        "templateName": "Misc 5"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 13,
                        "templateName": "Misc 6",
                        "isFolder": "true",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": 14,
                                "templateName": "Misc 7"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

If I search for `Subitem 1`, then the expected output is:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "templateName": "Item 1",
        "isFolder": "true",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "templateName": "Subitem 1",
                "isFolder": "true",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "templateName": "Misc 1",
                        "isFolder": "true",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": 4,
                                "templateName": "Misc 2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "templateName": "Item 2",
        "isFolder": "true",
        "children": [
            {   
                "id": 8,
                "templateName": "Subitem 1",
                "isFolder": "true",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 9,
                        "templateName": "Misc 1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But the answer in the referenced Q&A returns objects without `children` properties.

I tried to modify that answer's code and also I added `isFolder` props for additional validation for my help. But I cannot make it return the expected output above.

Comment: Can you add your actual code?

Comment: Please make sure the question contains the problem statement. Although a link to another Q&A can be helpful, the essence should be in the current question. So far it is not specified what the input is, and expected output. An example of input/output would be useful. Also add the code you are trying with (you can always add attribution).

Comment: After your edit: why does the output have the same structure repeated? Shouldn't the id remain unique?

Comment: I edited output again. Nothing but removed the duplicate. If I search `Subitem 1`, it id inside `Item 1`. So I want the output Item 1 with only Subitem 1 and their children. Same, if subitem 1 where present in other child, I want that complete parent track

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with a recursive function that copies the tree, but only retaining children that have a deeper match. When a node matches, no deeper recursion is needed, as then the whole subtree below that node remains included.

Here I have used `map` and a chained `filter(Boolean)`. You could achieve the same with `reduce`. The `map` will map nodes to `false` when there is no match somewhere in the subtree rooted by that node. These `false` values are then eliminated by `filter(Boolean)`:

```js
function deepFilter(nodes, cb) {
    return nodes.map(node => {
        if (cb(node)) return node;
        let children = deepFilter(node.children || [], cb);
        return children.length && { ...node,  children };
    }).filter(Boolean);
}

const forest = [{"id": 1,"templateName": "Item 1","isFolder": "true","children": [{"id": 2,"templateName": "Subitem 1","isFolder": "true","children": [{"id": 3,"templateName": "Misc 1","isFolder": "true","children": [{"id": 4,"templateName": "Misc 2"}]}]},{"id": 5,"templateName": "Subitem 2","isFolder": "true","children": [{"id": 6,"templateName": "Misc 3"}]}]},{"id": 7,"templateName": "Item 2","isFolder": "true","children": [{"id": 8,"templateName": "Subitem 1","isFolder": "true","children": [{"id": 9,"templateName": "Misc 1"}]},{"id": 10,"templateName": "Subitem 8","isFolder": "true","children": [{"id": 11,"templateName": "Misc 4"},{"id": 12,"templateName": "Misc 5"},{"id": 13,"templateName": "Misc 6","isFolder": "true","children": [{"id": 14,"templateName": "Misc 7"}]}]}]}];

const result = deepFilter(forest, node =>
    node.templateName.includes("Subitem 1")
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Or, trade time for space and keep `[...traverse(forest)]` around as an index.  And, if searching by `templateName` is a regular thing, reduce that array to an object keyed by templateName.

Comment: @trincot Thanks for answer and edited the question. I saw your code and output. But I want a output of complete tree structure if any match found. I added my expected output in the question. Please look into that

Comment: I have rewritten my answer.